# How to customize text of "Top Rated" UITabBar item?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

This should be simple, but I've scoured the Internet to no avail:

Is it possible to change the text of a default Tab Bar item identifier, such as "Top Rated"? I'd like to use the star icon, so either changing the text or finding the location of the icon and using with a custom identifier would work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system tab bar items, cannot be changed.  You can, however, use your own icon which could mimic that of the Top Rated icon.

You would use the icon as such:

```
UITabBarItem *myItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Custom Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage"] tag:0];
```